# GridView onclick to a new activity

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity

I have this code :
    public class Main extends Activity {

```
GridView gridView;

static final String[] numbers = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
        "6", "7" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.grid);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity1.class);
           startActivity(i);


        }
    });
}
```

I would like when i click on 1 go to activity1, when i click 2 go to activity2 and so on..

Is it even possible?

Comment: ... or you could have a single "secondary Activity" and pass the number to it. Then do what you want with that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible

Have your activity names in a String array

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Activity1", "Activtiy2", "Activity3" };
```

Then in onItemClick

```
String val = values[arg2]; // arg2 is the index of item
Class ourClass  = Class.forName("yourpackagename."+val);
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,ourClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have an error in 
    String val = values[postion];

Comment: @MobiusApps din't you see the edit. its `values[arg2]`. Read the post again and the comment next to //.

Comment: i saw it, not i have this error "Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: @MobiusApps put a try catch around the block of code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Raghunandan i've managed to solve it like this :

```
String val = activities[arg2]; // arg2 is the index of item
            Class ourClass = null;
            try {
                 ourClass  = Class.forName("com.example.challenge."+val);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Day02.this,ourClass);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```